# Laravel artisan Migrate:Fresh not working if used in system context

Tags: php, laravel, shell, command, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to create a command that runs the migrate:fresh command in a different folder in order to reset a mock application while at the same time running the migrate:fresh in the current folder. It is set up like so:

```php
$command = sprintf('(cd %s && php artisan migrate:fresh)', $path); 
system($command);
```

Here the path is an absolute path. Running this command gives output:

```
Dropped all tables successfully.
Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (16.60ms)
```

However, when verifying in the database of the application it is *supposed* to be migrating, all the data is still there and nothing has been freshly setup. So, it seems as if the data is not being properly migrated even though Laravel is claiming it is.

At first I presumed it was because of the call using system. So I have used exec, shell_exec and the Symfony Process. Additionally, because I thought it may have been a permissions issue, I have tried to run the command with sudo. This did not help. Laravel version is 8.8

```php
$command = sprintf('(cd %s && php artisan migrate:fresh)', $path); 
exec($command);
shell_exec($command);

$process = Process::fromShellCommandline($command);
$process->run();
```

Each seemed to be 'working' with output being given similar as above. However, when verifying if the data was gone, it was still there. My expectation is that after having made a subshell and seeing the output, the process had actually properly run. But this seems not to be the case.

Comment: The only thing that springs in my eye is that you are talking about the standard output of the artisan command only, but not it's exit status. Have you tried capturing it's exit status code? What is it?

Comment: I can also add that, depending on how you have your system setup, it may be using the `environment variables` from the original laravel project, so are you sure it is not wiping out the laravel's caller instead of the other system? Another solution (and I would say better one), would be to do an HTTP call to that other laravel system if possible, or just know which queue it is using and dispatch an event so that other system gets it and triggers, internally, the `migrate:fresh` with `$this->artisan(...)`

Comment: Interestingly enough - it is running against the wrong environment, after an additional verification. So it is not running the artisan that is in the file I am referring to, instead it is running against the artisan of the local folder. Which.. is a problem.

Comment: Additionally - the exit status code is 0. There is no failure on the call itself - the logging is there and artisan pretends to have ran. But it has not.

Answer (score 0):

Matiaslauriti had the right of it. It was actually running on the wrong environment thus it was actually overwriting the main database. The reason why it 'seemed' okay is that the migrate:fresh on that database is ran after the mock database has been migrated.

In the end, what ended up fixing my issue was setting the environment in a hard manner, creation a construction like this (mind, I am using Dotenv to create maps for my environment variables and load the files):

```php
try {
    putenv('DB_DATABASE=' . $mockEnv['DB_DATABASE']);
    system(sprintf('cd %s && php artisan migrate:fresh', $path));
} finally { 
    putenv('DB_DATABASE=' . $actualEnv['DB_DATABASE']);
}
```

I attempt the migration, should it fail for *ANY REASON*, the environment will still be put back. The command itself is taking the application down and up, so I am not worried about checks in that regard.